# Error in http_statuses - subscript out of bounds

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

Can someone explain me why *session2* gives me following error:

```
library("rvest")
uastring = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session = html_session("https://www.linkedin.com/job/", user_agent(uastring))
session2 = html_session("https://www.linkedin.com/job/")
```

> Error in http_statuses[[as.character(status)]] : subscript out of
>   bounds

I have these example from https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/

How I can check which value of *uastring* I have to put to *html_session* (for different sites). I don't ask about this specific site (I put it here because it's comes from tutorial).

Comment: There must be a "ToS violation hackathon" going on or something. https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement : _"Use manual or automated software, devices, scripts robots, other means or processes to access, “scrape,” “crawl” or “spider” the Services or any related data or information;"_  (just b/c you can !== shld do)

Comment: Where I can check appropriate value of uastring (html session argument)?

Comment: _"Can you help me steal information from websites that use ToS legal usage contracts and make efforts to restrict scraping to user-agents that are associated with humans using browsers because they really don't want folks stealing their info?"_

Comment: I use this example (LinkedIn) because it's shown in tutorial. In this question I'm asking about general method, not this specific case.

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php